# Bones not Following Rotation of Armature

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bone.constraints

I have an animation of my model which I would like to orientate in a different direction. This is normally a trivial thing to do, however, this models bones are not orientating themselves relative to the origin.

Here is the model in the original position. The origin is slightly off-centre because the animation is a mixamo animation of sitting down from standing.

[image: Original Position]

Here is what happens when I try to turn the model:

[image: Rotated Position]

You can see that for some reason the legs are retaining the original orientation while the rest of the model rotates correctly. You can also see the mixamo rig I have been using to make adjustments to the animation. All other animations I have done like this have worked fine - I can't figure out what is going wrong with this one.

The IK and FK follow "should" be set to "world space" and "replace", just as the other bones that have rotated correctly have. What could it be? The hips are correct...the belt is parented to the bone and that's orientated correctly.

[image]

Comment: Hello, what are you trying to rotate exactly? Maybe share your file, at least the armature?

Comment: It's going to depend on your constraints.  You could be targeting empties-- I see a few in your scene-- and if those don't rotate with the armature object, then you'll end up with a different pose.  You could be using constraints in world space, like a world space limit rotation, and when you rotate your armature, those are going to differ.  We need to see the armature (the file) to have any hope of helping.

Comment: Ok I figured out (I think) what was going wrong. Somehow I used constraints targeting an actual armature with animation (the method by which you copy an armature to your models armature). Somehow I deleted that armature but but it was invisible somewhere in the file. Because the model armature was targetting that armature and it wasn't included in the location and rotation and transform, part of the armature wasn't rotating.

Comment: "You could be targeting empties" - no see above. The empties are for IK constraints which I have turned off while I try to sort out why the armature isn't working.

Comment: Blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=7Sdnb6QJ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/7Sdnb6QJ/)

Comment: In the fle you provided, the animation rig's bones seem to still be constrained to copy the rotations of the bones from "Sit then Cross Legs" armature. Perhaps a simple way to fix this would be to rotate both the armatures. Alternatively, perhaps a script can be made to bake the animation to the animation rig and then remove the constraints used for the retargeting, so that you get a full keyframe animation free from the original. Perhaps the rigging system you used have such tools.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This was in fact the answer which I figured out myself. I think what happened is that the mixamo armature would not target the mixamo animation and I had to use the "brute" force method by adding constraints. It's a long time since I worked on this model.